# forcing a notifyChanged() on a ListPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-sharedpreferences

I have a ListPreference and would like to achieve a behavior equivalent to a notifyChanged() every time I click on a ListPreference item **even** if this item is the currently selected one.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `DropDownPreference` and this library: https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix.
It seems that simply switching to a `ListPreference` solved my issue.
Clicking on an already selected item from the list will trigger notifyChanged().